# Java: can't load applications.properties

Tags: java, resources, properties, jar, manifest

I have a basic executable JAR with manifest.txt containg the MainClass and some other jar dependencies.

I wanted to move my config file, "application.properties" outside the jar into a directory where it's easy to configure/maintain.  The java code does a simple ResourceBundle.getBundle('application.props') to load it.

I have a directory setup that looks like this:

```
/bin/run.sh
/lib/stuff.jar
/common/application.properties
```

My run.sh looks similiar to this:

```
 TOOLNAME="stuff.jar"
 CLASSPATH="../common"
 java -cp ${CLASSPATH} -Dapplication.props=application  -jar ../lib/${TOOLNAME}.jar &
```

When I run this, the jar runs, but still seems unable to find the application.properties file.

I'm not sure if this is somehow due to the manifest.txt overriding my -D parameter.
Also wondering, is it possible to move the classpath for this "../common" folder into the manifest.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your parameter `-jar`. If you specify that, the parameter `-cp` is ignored.

You can put your classpath into your manifest, the path specified there is relative to the surrounding path of the jar. If you specify `../common` there, you will be able to access your `application.properties` as a resource.

Comment: Thanks.!  So far I've tried putting "../common" in the manifest classpath as suggested, but it still does not appear to see it.  The -jar option doesn't overwrite -D parameters too, does it?

Comment: I don't believe that `-D` is ignored here. You could try it by removing your `-jar` parameter, putting your jar into the `-cp` arguments and specifying your main class explicitly. If everything works then, you can go back and try to make the `-jar` parameter work.

Comment: It appears to work if I put the properties file in the same directory as the jar and specify "." in the manifest classpath.  It does not work if i specify "../common" though, could this perhaps be a security feature to restrict the classpath to only dirs underneath?

Comment: it worked!  i had to specify it as ../common/   , it didn't work without the trailing slash

Comment: Just an FYI in case someone else comes along and reads this...  using ../{folder name}/ did not work for me.  In my case ./{folder name}/ worked.